# Context Menu not showing when pressing Shift+f10 in GridView Column

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, contextmenu

I have a ListView which consist of a GridView

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="GridViewContextMenu.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridViewContextMenu"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="DynamicPeriodContextMenu" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <MenuItem Header="Open" />
            <MenuItem Header="SetAsComparativePeriod"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="DeletePeriod"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Properties"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid ContextMenu="{StaticResource DynamicPeriodContextMenu}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Model">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Company">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Registration">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Registration}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
namespace GridViewContextMenu
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
            this.DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GridViewContextMenu
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Car> mCars;

        public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
        {
            get
            {
                if (mCars == null)
                {
                    mCars = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Car>();
                }
                return mCars;
            }
            set
            {
                mCars = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Cars");
            }
        }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Car car = new Car();
                car.Company = "Company" + i;
                car.Model = "Model" + i;
                car.Name = "Name" + i;
                car.Registration = "Registration" + i;
                Cars.Add(car);
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Model Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GridViewContextMenu
{
    public class Car : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private System.String mName;

        public System.String Name
        {
            get { return mName; }
            set
            {
                mName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        private System.String mModel;

        public System.String Model
        {
            get { return mModel; }
            set
            {
                mModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Model");
            }
        }
        private System.String mCompany;

        public System.String Company
        {
            get { return mCompany; }
            set
            {
                mCompany = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Company");
            }
        }
        private System.String mRegistration;

        public System.String Registration
        {
            get { return mRegistration; }
            set
            {
                mRegistration = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Registration");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have written all so that it's easy for one to understand,

When i click Name Column cell it's showing the `DynamicPeriodContextMenu` but when i press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> it's not showing the context Menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open the ContextMenu with right click WPF knows exactly where you clicked (on the Grid in your cell template) and it opens the ContextMenu associated to the Grid.

Using the Shift+F10 will only work (out of the box) for a ContextMenu on the ListView itself.

For example if I set Focusable = True on the Grid in your template and then use Tab to set the focus on that Grid, then I can use Shift+F10 just fine.

```
                <Grid ContextMenu="{StaticResource DynamicPeriodContextMenu}"
                      Focusable="True">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: Is there a way by which i don't have to hit tab?

Comment: What is the reason to put the ContextMenu in the grid cell? Do you want different ContextMenus for different columns? If so, how will you differentiate between columns when using shortcuts?

Comment: That was the idea to set different context menus for different columns..The context menu should appear on shift +f10 when user clicks/selects that particular column cell.

Comment: i guess you're right this makes no sense that specific context menu appears on selection of a listviewitem. Thanks for your Answer :)